# Can a group of fields be added to $form in buildForm()?

Tags: forms, 8

I am defining a custom form to be added to the `$build` array of a specific node, using form elements as defined [here.](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements?object_name_1=&object_name_2=All&object_name=&summary=&page=1)

Is it possible to add a field collection to the `$form` array, like `'#type' => 'field_collection'` or something similar?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question and define "field collection" as meaning a group of form elements so as not to be confused with the field collection module?

Comment: Done @mradcliffe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also [Details](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Details.php/class/Details/8.2.x):

> Provides a render element for a details element, similar to a fieldset.

```
$form['author'] = array(
  '#type' => 'details',
  '#title' => $this->t('Author'),
  '#open' => TRUE
);

$form['author']['name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => $this->t('Name'),
);
```

Here is a link to more documentation about details.
https://www.drupal.org/node/1898824

The documentation suggests:

> When to use Fieldsets over Details
>
> - When they are semantically related like a date field with year,    month, day, time.

Here is the change record from D7 to D8.
https://www.drupal.org/node/1852020

> All collapsible fieldsets have been replaced with HTML5 details elements

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this. What is the advantage of choosing details over fieldset? I'm not fully understanding from the API doc.

Comment: This is an html5 tag. In an ideal world all browsers would support this without the help of javascript.

Comment: Added some more information about details and a link to the change record and documentation.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out [fieldset](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Fieldset.php/class/Fieldset/8.2.x) is what I was looking for:

> Provides a render element for a group of form elements.